# Prolog - create simple function

Tags: prolog

I have a function that uses 4 parameters, called `tile` . It is designed to work the following way :

```
tile(?E, ?S, ?W, ?N, ?ID)
```

I would like a getter function that given an ID, it returns the first 4 parameters: `E, S, W` and `N`.
I have tried something like:

```
coordonates(tile(E,S,W,N,L), (E,S,W,N)).
```

But it does not return the actual values, only `true`.
If I type `tile(E, S, W, N, #1)` in the terminal I get the desired result but I do not know what exactly is returned (a list maybe?).

Comment: *I have a function that uses 4 parameters*... you actually have a *predicate* that has *5* arguments. *If I type `tile(E, S, W, N, #1)` in the terminal **I get the desired result but I do not know what exactly is returned***. Note that *predicates* (they are not functions!) do not return values. They succeed or fail only. A `true` response means it succeeded.

Comment: @lurker "a true response means it succeeded" ... what does a *false* response mean ? Thx.

Comment: A *false* response means it failed to find any further solutions. The *false* or *no* response could occur after finding one or more solutions, but if there's a remaining choice point and no more solutions to be found, you can get the *false* or *no* response. In other words, you can call a predicate and it may fail without any solutions, or it may successfully produce one or more solutions, then finally fail seeking any more. That's a fundamental difference between Prolog behavior and other programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose our facts describing `tile` looks as follows:

```
tile(p1,p2,p3,p4,id1).
tile(q1,q2,q3,q4,id2).
tile(r1,r2,r3,r4,id3).
```

In this we have a finite number of facts. That can be checked by the most general query for `tile`:

```
?- tile(E,S,W,N,I).
E = p1,
S = p2,
W = p3,
N = p4,
I = id1 ;             % <---- user input ; to continue
E = q1,
S = q2,
W = q3,
N = q4,
I = id2 ;             % <---- user input ; to continue
E = r1,
S = r2,
W = r3,
N = r4,
I = id3.              % <---- toplevel outputs . -- we're done
```

So in theory, we could define `coordonates` as follows:

```
coordonates(id1, t(p1, p2, p3, p4)).
coordonates(id2, t(q1, q2, q3, q4)).
coordonates(id3, t(r1, r2, r3, r4)).
```

which could be queried for `id2` as follows:

```
?- coordonates(id2,X).
X = t(q1, q2, q3, q4).
```

I used the functor `t` to group the solution, to make clear that it is not the predicate `tile` we defined earlier. There's also a lot of repetition in this definition which is already a hint, that we can do better.   What we are looking for is a rule which tells us how, given we have a answer for `tile`, we can describe `coordonates`. In logical terms, this is written as an implication of the form: goal1 ∧ ... ∧ goalN → head. which means "Suppose I know that goal1 to goalN is true, then I also know that head is true." In Prolog, this is written backwards:

```
head :-
  goal1,
  % ...
  goalN.
```

Let's go back to our task: we know something about a tile and we want to describe how the projection looks like. This means, our code looks as follows:

```
coordonates( ... ) :-
  % ...
  tile(E,S,W,N,I).
```

The body `tile(E,S,W,N,I)` is the most general form we can write (see our query above) and can be read as "suppose I have any tile at coordinates E S W N with id I". Now we only need to fill in, how `coordonates` should look like. We know it has two arguments, because it relates the id with the four other elements. Lets give them names, say `Id` and `Coords`:

```
coordonates(Id, Coords) :-
  % ...
  tile(E,S,W,N,I).
```

Now we only need to find out how to relate E,S,E,N and I with Id and Coords. One is easy: `Id` is just `I`. The other one is also not too hard, we just need to group the coordinates into one term. We can pick an arbitrary one, but already above decided to take `t`, so we will stick with it:

```
coordonates(Id, Coords) :-
  Id = I,
  Coords = t(E,S,W,N),
  tile(E,S,W,N,I).
```

This already works as we expect:

```
?- coordonates(X,Y).
X = id1,
Y = t(p1, p2, p3, p4) ;
X = id2,
Y = t(q1, q2, q3, q4) ;
X = id3,
Y = t(r1, r2, r3, r4).
```

Now we can make one observation: if two terms are equal, we can use one instead of the other. So instead of writing `Id = I`, we can just reuse `Id`. The same goes for `Coords` and `t(E,S,W,N)`:

```
coordonates(I, t(E,S,W,N)) :-
    tile(E,S,W,N,I).
```

It couldn't be much shorter :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare 'E, S, W and N' so that prolog can unify those parameters with the input when you make the query. Something like (In the most basic case):

```
tile(['cordE1','cordS1','cordW1','cordN1'],1).
tile(['cordE2','cordS2','cordW2','cordN2'],2).
tile(['cordE3','cordS3','cordW3','cordN3'],3).
```

Query:

```
?- tile(C,2).
C = [cordE2, cordS2, cordW2, cordN2].

?- tile(C,1).
C = [cordE1, cordS1, cordW1, cordN1].

?- tile(C,3).
C = [cordE3, cordS3, cordW3, cordN3].
```